# Logging into a website through a proxy

Tags: php, proxy

I need to develop a system that would log into a website, at regular intervals, through a remote server (I believe "proxy" is the term) and collect data from that website.

What would be the basic requirements, for a system like that, in terms of servers an software? Would I need more than a typical shared hosting plan?

I'm looking for a software solution that is based on PHP.

Edit: The collected data will be used for statistical purposes only - nothing illegal.

Comment: firstly you would require permission from the remote site.

Comment: @Dagon, do you mean the site that will be crawled or the remote server?

Comment: by "log into a website" you mean loggin in with a username and password ? or just request any/all pages to check they'r layout ?

Comment: @poelinca, good question. I mean logging in with a particular username and a password.

Comment: you can achive this using php cUrl , search around the web 'couse there are tons of "how-to login into a website using curl"

Comment: @poelinca, thanks, I wish you had posted that as an answer so I can upvote you.

Comment: @Emanuil: it's not realy all about upvotes/points but helping out . you're welcome

Comment: @poelinca, how about the server configuration? Does a typical shared hosting plan provide all that's necessary for the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP curl functions to request a page.
And Curl allows you to set a proxy like so:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://proxyaddress"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "xxx:xxx");
```

And I guess the reason for the downvotes is that it seems like you are trying to steal a design, but I guess you have a completely legit reason for doing what you want to do!

Comment: Thanks! It's a legit thing. If someone wants to steal a design she could just log in from her own computer - wouldn't need a proxy or a crawler.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to create a web crawler. That is how search engines index the web pages they search. This crawling is done by scripts called spiders or robots. It can be created easily using Perl. Check this http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2200 for a simple tutorial.

Comment: How do I go about doing that through a remote server? That's the tricky part for me.

Comment: Why the downvotes for the question and this answer? Please, somebody explain!

Comment: @Emanuil search engines do not conceal themselves behind proxy. as they have nothing to hide. There is no reason to use a proxy if you have site owner permiission. So, I assume you have not. I know, I cannot stop you but it's disgusting and you all help to make web even worse. Shame on you.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, the only reason I need a proxy (and I don't even know if I really need one) is because the data I need is available to US IPs only. I'm very concerned about the legal aspect of the things I do and promise you, I wouldn't want to do something illegal.

Comment: you could get a US hosting account, then no proxy will be needed. I host all my sites in the US even though i don't live there